# why is there an error in end process and end architecture?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

i have 2 errors. the errors are in end process and end architecture.
i have tried adding another end if but it is not helping.

```
Line 40: ERROR, syntax error near 'process'.
 Line 46: ERROR, syntax error near 'ARCHITECTURE'.
```

here is the full code

```
 LIBRARY ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY four_bit_new_counter IS
  port (clk , rst , start , stop : in std_logic ; 
        output : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        carry : out std_logic );
END ENTITY four_bit_new_counter;

ARCHITECTURE one OF four_bit_new_counter IS
signal qout: unsigned (3 downto 0);
signal cout: std_logic ;
BEGIN

    process (clk,rst,start,stop)
        begin
        if (rst ='1') then
          qout <= (qout'range => '0');
          cout <= '0' ;
      elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        cout <= '0' ;
        if start='1' and stop='0' then 
                  if qout = '9' then
                    cout <= '1' ;
                    qout <= '0' ;
                  else
          qout <= qout+1 ;
        endif ; 
      end process ; 

output <= std_logic_vector(qout);
carry <= cout ;


END ARCHITECTURE one;
```

Comment: For one, "endif" is not valid syntax in VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors preventing your design specification from analyzing.

`qout` is declared `unsigned (3 downto 0) and you perform an equality operation against the character literal`'9'`.

You later assign `qout` the value of the character literal `0` instead of `"0000"` or `x"0"` or `(qout'range => '0')` an aggregate expression you use for resent.

The `endif` fru1tbat mentions should be `end if`.

There are two more `end if` statements missing see below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity four_bit_new_counter is
    port (
        clk, rst, start,stop:   in  std_logic ; 
        output:                 out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        carry:                  out std_logic
    );
end entity four_bit_new_counter;

architecture one of four_bit_new_counter is 
    signal qout: unsigned (3 downto 0);
    signal cout: std_logic ; 
begin
    process (clk,rst) -- also included ,start,stop
    begin
        if rst ='1' then
             qout <= (qout'range => '0');
             cout <= '0' ;
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
            cout <= '0' ;
            if start = '1' and stop = '0' then 
                if qout = 9 then  -- was '9'
                    cout <= '1' ;
                    qout <= (qout'range => '0') ;  -- was '0'
                else
                    qout <= qout + 1 ;
                end if ;  -- was endif
            end if;       -- missing
        end if;           -- missing
    end process ; 

    output <= std_logic_vector(qout);
    carry <= cout ;

end architecture one;
```

And after those changes your design specification both analyzes and elaborates.

Incidentally the sensitivity list for the unlabelled process only requires `rst` and `clk`.

You can also use the IEEE package numeric_std in place of the Synopsys std_logic_arith.

The reason it complains near `process` and `architecture` are that these two reserved words are out of place inside a series of sequential statements inside an if statement *because* you have a series of `end if`s missing closing those if statements.